# Sending information between Activities in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

```
    fun kullaniciOlustur2(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext,KullaniciOlustur2::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("input",makeUsername.text.toString())
        intent.putExtra("input2",makeUserphone.text.toString())
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Mainactivity2 starts here..before this, I was using

```
val intent = intent 
val received: String = intent.getStringExtra("input")   
makeUsername.text = received
```

But this method doesn't work anymore.
I tried using `getIntent()` but couldn't get anything

```
   val intent = getIntent()
```

Comment: try this val intent =intent.getStringExtra("input")

Comment: or try with  val received = intent.extras.getString("input")

Comment: Thanks @ShwetaChauhan but its not worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @Deven your code is good but i cant sending the information to textbox.
After your code i wrote makeUsername.text = received 
But code have a red line from start to end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

> Activity 1

```
val intent = Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity::class.java) //not application context
intent.putExtra("input",makeUsername.text.toString())
intent.putExtra("input2",makeUserphone.text.toString())
startActivity(intent)
```

> Activity 2

inside onCreate() method use

```
val stringOne = getIntent().getStringExtra("input")
```

Or more cleaner way is

```
val extras = getIntent().getExtras()
if (null != extras) {
    val value = extras.getString("input")
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```

and please check similar answers in Java, you may be able to get the Idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) already told in another answer.

I also Use [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) to remove this kind of boilerplate code

Comment: Thanks @TapanHP its worked. Also i will trying the using Anko in my project a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Kotlin Anko, there are plenty of methods that will help you to remove this boilerplate code

check Anko Intents [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Intents)

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below Code:**
   The Code is same as Java .Just difference is kotlin do not have
 1. No semicolon at the end.
  2. to call another activity kotlin use ::

ex.KotlinActivity::class.java

```
startActivity(Intent(this, KotlinActivity::class.java).putExtra("DataTrasfer", ""))
```

**To Get Value:**

```
intent.getStringExtra("DataTrasfer")
```